# Only one horizontal line's got applied with CSS, the last one doesn't show up

Tags: html, css

I have the one issue with hr tags. There're two hrs in my html below which is decorated using CSS border. When I run the code the first one shows up as I intended nut the second one doesn't, even though they share the same CSS. How should I do???

Here's my code:

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 5px dotted #EAF6F6;
  width: 5%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle-container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="resources/profile.png" alt="peofile-picture">
      <h2>Hello.</h2>
      <p>Learning web development skills. Just a drunk girl who's longing for Britain.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div class="skills">
      <h2>My Skills.</h2>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img src="resources/coding.png" class="code-img" alt="coding">
        <h3>WEB designing</h3>
        <p>Please remember, I AM really a NEWBIE when it comes to designing the website.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img src="resources/beer.png" class="beer-img" alt="beer">
        <h3>Drinking. Yes, JUST a drinking.</h3>
        <p class="drink">Having good meal is pleasure. When it comes with good drink, that's far more better.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="contact-me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3>But if you're interested in me...</h3>
      <p>Please feel free to contact, there might be any help I can provide.</p>
      <a class="btn" href="mailto:fictional@gmail.com">CONTACT ME</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: They both show fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/t9nv4z1e/

Comment: Can you provide some snippet example. On CodePen everything works fine: https://codepen.io/JacekRatajewski/pen/NWgNwpX

Comment: So it possibly comes from other places such as browser? I've visited that Codepen but found that no hrs show up

Comment: @Maoooo You can't see them in the CodePen/JSFiddle either?

Comment: hhYes, both hrs show up OK (well, their top dashed borders show though they are very faint) for me with the code you have given. This must mean that something else is overwriting the second hr. One thing to do is go into your browser dev tools and inspect that second hr and see exactly what is formatting it, and hover over the element and its immediate predecessor(s) to see if they are hiding it.

Comment: Ahh! I confirmed the Dev Tools and there's one obstacles in other CSS so I managed to have it. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot an `hr` in your HTML, just check the picture below to understand :

[image]

Comment: Prefer copy and edit question's snippet than add screen because we can't copy/paste code in screenshoot